# Which game engines are geared towards making an open world game, like gta3 for example for mobiles

Tags: android, iphone, unity-game-engine

I've been coding for a long time and decided to take a year out to create an indie mobile game. I've been learning Unity and that looks like it can deliver what I want but just wanted to do some research before I dived into the development stage. The requirements are large, open, free roaming landscapes and publishing to the iPhone and Android phones. The language doesn't really matter as I know a few already.

Answer (score 1):

[Unity3D](http://www.unity3d.com) is the right choice for high end games to be deployed on mobile phones.

Answer (score 0):

Besides [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/) there are several 3D engines for iOS and Android:

- [Unreal engine](http://www.unrealengine.com/)
- [SIO2](http://sio2interactive.com/)
- [Proton](http://protonsdk.com/) - uses Irrlicht engine
- [ShiVa3D](http://www.stonetrip.com/)